# no instance of constructor "Name::Name" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, class-constructors

I use Visual Studio 2019. It shows me 6 errors. Please help
[compile error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lob5Q.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class Name{
    char name[20];
public:
    Name(){
        strcpy (name,""); cout<<'?';
}
    Name(char *fname){
        strcpy (name, fname); cout<<'?';
    }
};
int main(){
    Name names[3] ={Name("Chris"),Name("Jerry")};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: String literals are `const char*`, not `char*`

Comment: Change `Name(char *fname){` to `Name(const char *fname){`

Comment: My other recommendation is to look at the errors in the Output Tab. It often contains longer more verbose messages. As a professional developer I have changed the settings to have Visual Studio to not display the Errors List at all. I just use the Output Tab.

Comment: Thank you, guys. That's so helpful.